# What happens to a form from the time it's submitted in the view to before the data returns back to the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

This question has come up multiple times during interviews and I'm having trouble finding the answer on google. I think I'm using the wrong terminology when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For statrters this is the [MVC Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwkyk.png). Probably have seen it already, but basically as a user of the application. A good example of data being submitted in the view back to the controller is when a user attempts to create a new user. As first you may have a `<%= link_to 'Create New User', new_user_path %>` this will send a request back to the controller calling the `new` action in the `user_controller` upon this it will then render `app/users/new.html.erb` which will contain a form_for block that will render the partial which in most cases will be `:render :partial => 'form'`. From rendering the form and entering the relevant information **when the user submits the form the form and the data along with the form is submitted and a  POST request is made  which would most probably be `/users` in this case. This is mapped to the `create` action** in the UsersController as Rails uses the principle of convention over configuration.

```
def create
    @title = 'Create a user'
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      redirect_to usermanagement_path
      flash[:success] = 'Created successfully.'
    else
      @title = 'Create a user'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

In the above example what happens is that when the new action is called and the form is submitted it will pass in the new user into the params, upon this the it will try and save the user. I added a mailer so that when a particular user is created they receive a confirmation email. If the form doe not submit it will continue to render the `'new'` action.

Hope this clears things up